# How to call external javascript method on aspx page in the user control

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an external Javascript file which have many methods. I have a aspx page which consists of many controls like asp textbox,button etc. In this aspx page I am using an user control. This user control have a textbox. 
My external java script functions are getting called on the normal controls like textbox which are asp control. But same javascript funtion when i am trying to call for user control on the aspx page, this javascript function is not getting called.
Please tell me why it is not getting called, is there anything I am missing.
Below is sample JS calling on controls. Here JS function is getting called on Asp Textbox but not on user control.

```
  <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" onblur="MyJsFunc();"></asp:TextBox>
        <uc1:usertextbox id="txtUserTxt" runat="server" onblur="MyJsFunc();" />
    </div>
```

Comment: what does the user control do? are you sure it fires an onblur event?

Comment: Check browser console for javascript erros

Comment: yes onblur on first one is working fine but nothing happening on second one.

Comment: is there any specific way to call JS function on aspx for user control?

Comment: Are you binding the onblur to the textbox in your user control?  From what I remember of aspx, the onblur willl be passed through as a property to your usercontrol and then you would have to bind that property to your textbox in the usercontrol.  Can you show the codebehind and aspx for the usercontrol

Comment: my user control simply contains a asp textbox nothing else

Comment: @Pete, can you please provide any helpful link to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't tested and it's been a while since I did aspx so it may not be 100% accurate.  But say you have your user control code behind like so:

```
public partial class UserTextBox : UserControl
{
    public string OnBlur {get;set;} // add the property for onblur

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) // or can be on init
    {
        txtUserName.OnBlur = OnBlur;
    }
}
```

so in the above, `txtUserName` is the id of your normal textbox control (you have created on the aspx of your usercontrol) and you are just binding the onblur property that you have passed through your usercontrol to the onblur property of the normal textbox